# AngularJS ng-repeat rerender

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rendering, jquery-ui-sortable, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a simple app with AngularJS. The app make a async AJAX call to the server and the server returns an array like this:

```
{
    paragraphs: [
        {content: "content one"},
        {content: "cnt two"},
        {content: "random three"},
        {content: "last one yeeaah"}
    ]
}
```

So I'm setting this content to the StorageService factory via my set method. Everything is fine here.

I'm using `ng-repeat` to render the results and `JQuery UI sortable` to be able to change the order of the elements. When an item is swapped my script is calling the StorageService.swap method and the element order in StorageService is updated, **BUT ng-repeat isn't rerendering the change**, but if I remove/add or change the content it's working. How I can force the angular to rerender the ng-repeat?

**= JSFIDDLE =**

http://jsfiddle.net/6Jzx4/3/

**= Example =**

[image: Example]

When a swap occurs the ng-repeat should be rerendered, so the IDs are consecutive

**= Code =**

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Test" sortable>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data().paragraphs" class="box slide_content" id="{{$index}}"> 
        {{item.content}}, ID: {{$index}}
    </div>

    <input type="button" ng-click="add()" value="Add">
</div>
```

JS

```
var App = angular.module("MyApp", []);

App.controller("Test", function($scope, StorageService) {
    StorageService.set({
        paragraphs: [
            {content: "content one"},
            {content: "cnt two"},
            {content: "random three"},
            {content: "last one yeeaah"}
        ]
    });

    $scope.data = StorageService.get;

    $scope.add = StorageService.add;
});

App.directive("sortable", function(StorageService) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element[0]).sortable({
                cancel: ".disabled",
                items: "> .slide_content:not(.disabled)",
                start: function(e, t) {
                    t.item.data("start_pos", t.item.index());
                },
                stop: function(e, t) {
                    var r = t.item.data("start_pos");
                    if (r != t.item.index()) {
                                    StorageService.sort($(this).sortable("toArray"));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

App.factory('StorageService', function() {
    var output = {};

    return {
        set: function(data) {
            angular.copy(data, output);
            return output;
        },
        get: function() {
            return output;
        },
        add: function() {
            output.paragraphs.push({
                content: 'Content'
            });
        },
        sort: function(order) {
            var localOutput = [];

            for (var j in order) {
                var id = parseInt(order[j]);
                localOutput.push(output.paragraphs[id]);
            }

            console.log('new order', localOutput);

            output.paragraphs = localOutput;
            return output;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't see the relevant code in the jsfiddle...it also should be here in the post itself. I imagine it's because you didn't correctly utilize promises or you somehow ended up needing a `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: what is demo supposed to show us? Hard to help if demo doesn't replicate problem listed

Comment: @charlietfl well look the picture below "Example", it's explaining my problem. When a swap occurs ng-repeat isn't rerendered for some reason. See the middle picture ( after swap ), notice the second element has ID:2 and the third has ID:1, it should be visa-versa as showed in the picture 3.

Comment: can't troubleshoot from a  picture and no code. We understand what you expect, but without seeing the code can't do much. Can't you update demo to replicate it?

Comment: @charlietfl check out the fiddle. The code is pretty big, so I inserted it there, gonna put it in the post too now.

Comment: if you change angular scope from code outside angular, like your sortable handlers, have to inform angular using `$apply` otherwise it has no way to know to run a digest

Comment: The proximal issue is the need for `$apply` but then it looks like there are a number of other incompatibilities between jquery sortable and Angular.  So I'd recommend looking at [Angular UI sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable) It'll take some restructuring to get it going but then you should have something much more compatible.

Comment: @KayakDave yeah I switched to angular UI sortable and it worked. Write your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: Great- glad that worked for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular doesn't know you've changed the array.  Executing your sort inside a `scope.$apply()` will address that.

Note that I've added a `that` variable since `this` changes meaning inside the `apply`.

```
var that = this;
scope.$apply(function() {   
   StorageService.sort($(that).sortable("toArray"));
}
```

But that fix uncovers other problems that appear to be caused by the interaction between the jQuery sortable and Angular (here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Jzx4/4/) that shows an attempt at resolving the problems but still has issues).  These issues have been solved in [Angular UI Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable).  So a good path forward may be to switch to this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a few problems tho. Go to the fiddle, swap second field with third, press new: http://i.imgur.com/6fgbaRd.png , Another one: Swap last with first, press new, see what happens.

Comment: Right you'll need to update add to consider position.  Perhaps the other functions too- but you get the concept.  Here's one way to update add:  http://jsfiddle.net/6Jzx4/5/